# Stop IP-address from changing after reboot

Tags: networking, ip-address

My internal IP-address (hostname -I) changes every time I reboot the unit. How can I prevent this?

Comment: If you get your IP address via DHCP, the DHCP server may be the reason - then you can only avoid this by giving your machine a static IP. But this will not work if the address is inside the range of addresses provided by the DHCP server.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways how you can prevent the changing of your IP-address

- you can assign a fixed address to your interface (select "edit connections" from the network-indicator)
- you can tell the DHCP-server to make an address-reservation for your host

Comment: I did both but it still changed my internal IP (ipv4)

Comment: @Condolent in this case please [edit] your question with the result of `ip addr show`, so that we can see what settings you have - **and** indicate the address that keeps changing.